# Why does echo work through pipe but not cat with msmtp?

Tags: pipe, cat, echo, msmtp

This works:

> echo "yada yada" | msmtp my@mail.com

but not this:

> cat yadayada.txt | msmtp my@mail.com

which delivers the email with empty content.

**Why does echo work through pipe but not cat with msmtp ?**

Comment: Is your `yadayada.txt` formatted funny or have weird permissions?  It works fine for me catting it out.

Comment: yadayada.txt has u:rw g:rw o:r and is a multiline file.  
sample content:
=== rsync start === 2013-08-07 20:58:01
=== rsync stop  === 2013-08-07 21:00:50

Comment: this worked: tr -d ':' < yadayada.txt | msmtp my@mail.com

Comment: ':' was the culprit. thx @nerdwaller you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: That makes sense, since msmtp allows uses of something like `Subject: My subject line`.  Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

msmtp seems to rely on a wellformed email message in the file being read.

Ex.

```
Subject: My subject line  
My body text
```

Since I don't care about Subject etc
(I'm sending an email when a logfile is modified using incron)

> tr -d ':' < yadayada.txt | msmtp my@mail.com

is a Q&D way to get the logfile content sent using msmtp.